# Ubuntu boot hangs at "Starting NetBios Name server [OK]"

Tags: boot, server

I've got a Ubuntu server running 14.04.01-server-amd64-dell-t430.
It was working well, but yesterday there's a sudden power outage, after that, It was not able to be booted.

At the beginning, there are two same messages :
    "Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server".
The first message is followed by [OK], and another message is followed by [fail].
I solved this through inputting command:
    echo manual > /etc/init/samba-ad-dc.override.

After this command, there's no more fail message of "Starting SMB/CIFS", but the Ubuntu still boot failed.
This time, it hangs at
    Starting NetBios Name server [OK].
I tried to fsck in recovery mode, but it still hangs at the same place.
I have no clue how to solve it, could you please give some advice?